# iframe not displaying on mobile screen

Tags: android, html, css, iframe, mobile

My site has a couple of iframes across various pages, and all the iframes work when viewed on a computer, but when I view it on my android mobile, only the iframes sourced to youtube display any content. I'll include my code for both, but they're pretty standard.

Displays on mobile:

```
<iframe class='iframe-box-reading' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qzMQza8xZCc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Does not display on mobile:

```
<iframe frameborder="0"  src="https://medium.com/" class='iframe-box-reading' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Idk what's going on to make one work and not the other, but I'm also open to other solutions to embedding the sites, since that's all I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is I think the domain doesn't allow you to load their content inside an iframe. The error will actually be going to display from the console.

[image]

Comment: ohh, that makes sense. Is there a way around that?

Comment: not really if you don't have the control over the host or server.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I upvoted your answer, but it says that it was recorded but not displayed because my rank is under 15

Comment: you can mark it correct, but if you still can't, it's fine :) glad I helped! good luck!